# Merge( ) two Dataframe in Python, to see duplicates cases of ID

Tags: python, merge, duplicates

```
df1
   'ID'  'Prod1'  'Prod2'
1   223     2B      3C
2   224     3C      2B 
3   225     3C      4B
```

To see 'ID' duplicates I used merge:

```
dupli = pd.merge(df1, df1, how='inner', left_on='Prod1', right_on='Prod2')
```

and I got:

```
dupli
   'ID_x'  'ID_y' 'Prod1'  'Prod2'
1   223     224     2B      3C
2   224     223     3C      2B 
3   225     223     3C      2B
```

but I want something like this:

```
   'ID_x'    'ID_y'     'Prod1_x'  'Prod1_y'
1   223       224         2B      3C
2   224       223         3C      2B 
3   225    Something      3C      something
```

When I use merge, the function takes the first value, but I want that the function to replace and *not* take the first value, or check

```
Prod1==Prod2 and Prod2==Prod1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following produces the result table you're looking. To make sure that `Prod1==Prod2 and Prod2==Prod1` is checked, just merge on `['Prod1, 'Prod2']` and `['Prod2', 'Prod1']` using a left join and select the columns you want.

```
(pd
.merge(df1, df1, how='left', left_on=['Prod1', 'Prod2'], right_on=['Prod2', 'Prod1'])
[['ID_x', 'ID_y', 'Prod1_x', 'Prod1_y']]
)
```

output:

```
   ID_x   ID_y Prod1_x Prod1_y
0   223  224.0      2B      3C
1   224  223.0      3C      2B
2   225    NaN      3C     NaN
```